# want to run a python script through azure ml and schedule it

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I was trying to run a python file though azure ml and later schedule it, I noticed that even after the script is working as per the recurrence defined time, result is not getting updated, I am trying to get data from snowflake table and store it as a csv file in blob storage account, first run was successfull but then I updated my snowflake table and ran the same block of code again, till pipeline run, it's running also, not giving error but it's not updating my csv file again, I tried for different usecases also I'm noticing that it's giving same result again and again till I'm doing some changes in my python script, if I'm doing any changes in python script then it's actually running again

````
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azureml.core import Workspace
import os
import azureml.core
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset, Datastore, ComputeTarget, Experiment, ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep
from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline
from azure.ai.ml.entities import AmlCompute
from azureml.core import Environment

ws = Workspace.from_config()
subscription_id = "**"
resource_group = "**"
workspace = "\*\*\*\*"

ml_client = MLClient(DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='date_test')

compute_cluster = "datetime"

prep_step = PythonScriptStep(name='prep step',
script_name="datetimescript.py", #datetimescript.py contains the python script
source_directory="dynamic",
compute_target=compute_cluster,
allow_reuse=False)

job_env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name = 'datetime_testenvironment', file_path = './conda_train.yaml') #conda_train.yaml contains all dependency

train_src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory="dynamic",
script='datetimescript.py',
compute_target=compute_cluster,
environment=job_env)

train_step = PythonScriptStep(name='train step',
source_directory=train_src.source_directory,
script_name=train_src.script,
runconfig=train_src.run_config)
mybatchpipeline = Pipeline(ws, steps=\[train_step\])
run = exp.submit(mybatchpipeline)

run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

\#I noticed that even running these code again manually isn't updating results

\#datetimescript.py:-

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
import json
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
from datetime import datetime, timezone

connection_parameters = json.load(open(r"connection.json"))
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
session.sql_simplifier_enabled = True
session.sql('USE ROLE "MY_ROLE";').collect()

df = pd.DataFrame(session.sql('select \* from "MY_TABLE";').collect())

accountUrl="https://**.blob.core.windows.net"
containerName=""
blobName='tableSf.csv'
credentials= "**\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*"
blob_client = BlobClient(account_url=accountUrl ,container_name= containerName, blob_name= blobName,credential=credentials )  
output = SKILL_MASTER.to_csv(index=False, header=True, encoding="utf-8")
blob_client.upload_blob(output, overwrite=True)
print("job successfull!")
print(curr_dt)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work in azure for ml purposes but I used python with Azure Functions to manage files on sharepoint. In Azure functions there are triggers that execute the scripts. Hope it helps.